# ¿Cómo puedo enviar un entero de un método a otra clase?

Tags: java, class

Tengo el siguiente método:

```
public void enviarN(){
        int n = Integer.parseInt(txtn.getText());
    }
```

El cual está almacenando un valor de un textField.

(La clase en donde está dicho método es):

```
public class Matriz extends javax.swing.JFrame {...}
```

Y lo que necesito es poder enviar ese valor a otra clase donde estoy utilizando métodos de *Graphics*, para dibujar círculos al azar dependiendo el valor que tenga la variable **n**

Dicha clase la tengo tal que así:

```
public class DrawGraph extends JPanel{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Random azar = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < [acá necesito el valor de n]; i++) {
            g.setColor(new Color(azar.nextInt(255),azar.nextInt(255),azar.nextInt(255)));
            g.fillOval(azar.nextInt(230), azar.nextInt(230), 32, 32);
        }
    } 
}
```

Me gustaría saber cómo mandar el entero **n** del método *enviarN()* para poder usarlo en el método *paintComponent(Graphics g)* de la clase *DrawGraph*

Comment: Cómo usas la clase `DrawGraph` desde `Matriz`?

Comment: Quiero crear un nuevo objeto: `DrawGraph dNodos = new DrawGraph();` y eso añadirlo a un jDialog o a un jPanel por medio de `.add`, no se si a eso te refieres.

Comment: Te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y agregues este modo en que planeas usar dicha clase para que esté completa.

Comment: Por otro lado, hacer lo que pides es tan simple como definir un constructor en `DrawGraph` que espere un entero como parámetro y al momento de crear la instancia le pasas `n`.

Comment: ¿Pero cómo me quedaria el método de enviar el entero?

Comment: Edita la pregunta para que la respuesta se base en lo que solicitas.

Comment: Listo, ya está editada la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es muy simple, puedes crear un propiedad donde guardar el valor recibido en la primera clase y metodo "get", luego instancias la primera clase en la segunda clase, y llamas el metodo get.